# In mongoDB map function emit full document without assigning (key,values) pair to a varchar

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

```
var map = function() {
    var values = {d_sno : this.d_sno, type : this.type};
    emit(this._id, values);
};
```

In the map function above I am assigning `(key,value)` pair to a varchar and emit that varchar. I want to emit the whole document without assigning `(key,value)` pair to a varchar.

Comment: Usually you would not want to as this defeats the purpose of the "reduce" function for unique keys. You can always just delete the `_id` key after copying the reference and just return the `this` portion. Avoids un-necessary duplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can emit the whole document like this:

```
var map = function() {
    emit(this._id, this);
};
```

By emitting the whole document as a value, the emitted document will look like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a6bd394aaee8df24b45dc5"), 
    "value" : { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("53a6bd394aaee8df24b45dc5"), 
        "d_sno" : "foo", 
        "type" : "bar", 
        /* ... other fields */
    } 
}
```

The problem with this approach is that you will have _id of the documents in the value and in the key (because you're emitting _id as a key).

To get rid of the _id in the emitted value you can use this approach:

```
var map = function() {
   var key = this._id;
   var value = this;
   delete value._id;
   emit(key, value);
};
```

But you should be careful when emitting whole documents because a single emit can only hold half of MongoDB’s maximum BSON document size (which is currently 16 MB).